# Image wont show up html/css

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm having some problem showing up  my YD LOGO

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'product_sans_regular';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'product_sans_bold';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'product_sans_italic';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'product_sans_bold_italic';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold_italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold_italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold_italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold_italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/assets/fonts/product_sans_bold_italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    /* top: -50%; */
    top: 0;
    /* left: -50%; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(assets/daniel-leone-197357.jpg);
}

.Logo1 {
    margin-top: 18px;

}

.Header {
    font-family: 'product_sans_bold', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    /*    left:  851px;*/
    color: white;
    font-size: 120px;
    bottom: 580px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}

.Header1 {
    font-family: 'product_sans_bold', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    /*    left:  851px;*/
    color: white;
    font-size: 90px;
    bottom: 455px;
    left: 40px;
}

.Instagram {
    margin-top: 878px;
    margin-left: 1015px;
}

.Twitter {
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-left: 910px;
}

.YoungDevs {
    margin-top: -90px;
}

.ss {
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left:  1107px;
    margin-top: -68px;
}
.YD{
/*    margin-bottom: 100px;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   
    <div class="Logo1"> <img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="Logo1" style="width:90px; height: auto"> </div>
    <center>
        <div class="Header"> Hexovo </div>
    </center>
    <div class="Header1"> Made To Inspire.</div>
    <div class="Instagram">
        <div style="font-size:3.5em; color:white"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Twitter">
        <div style="font-size:3.5em; color:white"> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ss">     <img src="assets/ss.png" alt="ss"> </div>
    <center>  <div class="YD"> <img src="assets/YD.png" alt="YD1"</div>  </center>
</body>


</html>
```

The Image calls 'YD' wont show up for some reason even though other images show up such as Instagram , ss, Twitter. I've tried to centre it to make it at least show up for me to use and I don't understand why it wont work.Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see in the network tab? Look carefully at your `/`s.

Comment: you didn't close your last img tag

Comment: <center>  <div class="YD"> <img src="assets/YD.png" alt="YD1"></div>  </center> Done it but doesn't work

Comment: Is your `YD.png` file in a folder called `assets` that is at the same level as the file you are attempting to load the image on? And have you ensured that the file actually exists on the server by manually navigating there? You're using an absolute path for your logo, but a relative path for your `YD` file. Note that `/` prefix.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes I have it is in my assets folder and I'm trying to load that image. I've manually navigated it there too

Comment: @obsidianAge I've also used inspect element I can hover over the div in the developer too but not see it on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to close your `<img>` tag:
    `<img src="assets/YD.png" alt="YD1">`

**Update**: Given your responses to others' answers, this sounds like it is a path problem. In your CSS you have absolute paths set, in your HTML you have relative. Try adding the slash before "assets":
    `<img src="/assets/YD.png" alt="YD1">`

Comment: Is your "assets" directory at the top-level of your public html folder? IE: domain.com/assets?

Comment: @hexmania-hexy Does the image exists in specified path?
Can you link us the image?

Comment: I've figured it out the directory was suppose to be assets/YD.png not /assets/YD.png